# What is the easiest way to decrease the linespread in a table of contents?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script

Using the scrartcl class for a report I am writing, I would like to have only the sections show up in the table of contents. Although I manage to do that, the linespread looks too big in my eyes, and I think this is a consequence of the reduced toc depth:

[image]

For this reason, I would like to reduce the linespread locally. I tried to put a `{spacing}` around my code like this:

```
\begin{spacing}{0.5}
   \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
   \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
   \vspace*{-1cm}
   \tableofcontents
   \vspace*{-0.5cm}
   \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{spacing}
```

Which will not work, however. **What is the easiest way to decrease the linespread here?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [tocstyle](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) package that comes with the [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle. But you will get a warning about the Alpha state of the package so you should use it with caution. At least the below code works as desired.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newtocstyle{compact}{%
  \settocfeature[1]{entryhook}{\bfseries}%
  \settocfeature[1]{entryvskip}{0pt plus 2pt}%
  \settocfeature[1]{leaders}{\hfill}%
}
\usetocstyle{compact}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \bigskip
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

And as always, the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution.

---

[image]

Comment: The package generating the alpha warning is named `tocstyle`.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the command `\l@section` which is (beside other things) responsible for setting the vertical space before a section entry in the ToC.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.0em}{\z@}{}{}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{bla}

\section{blubb}

\section{foo}

\subsection{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This depends on the definition of internal commands and does not work with current KOMA-Script release.

Answer (score 5):

Since KOMA-Script 3.20 you can use option `tocbeforeskip` of command `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the distance before a TOC entry:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]% Needs at least KOMA-Script 3.20!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=0pt]{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]