# Increase Linespread in Koma Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Trying to change line spread between the entries (between chapter and first section and then between sections) in the Table of Contents. I looked at the tocstyle package and the phrase "line spread" doesn't show up. There's a question about how to *decrease* linespacing but not *increase* linespacing: [What is the easiest way to decrease the linespread in a table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-decrease-the-linespread-in-a-table-of-contents)

I commented out my failed effort to use the \leading package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=22pt,letterpaper,DIV=10,headings=small]  {scrbook} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
%%\usepackage{leading}

\begin{document}
%%\begin{\leading{5mm}}
\tableofcontents
%%\end{\leading{5mm}}
\chapter{Big Chapter}
\section{Apple}
\blindtext{2}
\section{Banana}
\blindtext{2}
\section{Clementine}
\section{Durazno}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a change of the line-spread, e.g., after the heading of the ToC, from within the document preamble:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=22pt,letterpaper,DIV=10,headings=small]  {scrbook} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\AfterTOCHead{\linespread{1.5}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\section{Longer entry on level 1 (section) needing two lines}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, this would not only increase the distance between entries but also in an entry (see section 1.3). If you want to change the distance between the entries only, you can use the solution from the linked question:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=22pt,letterpaper,DIV=10,headings=small]  {scrbook} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocbeforeskip=.5\baselineskip]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\section{Longer entry on level 1 (section) needing two lines}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `setspace` package:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=22pt,letterpaper,DIV=10,headings=small]  {scrbook} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\setstretch{1.5}
\tableofcontents
\egroup
\chapter{Big Chapter}
\section{Apple}
\blindtext{2}
\section{Banana}
\blindtext{2}
\section{Clementine}
\section{Durazno}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\setstretch{1.5}` for the whole `\tableofcontents` does set the distances above and below the heading and the heading also with increases line spread. This results in another vertical position of the heading than for the headings of other chapters and a very large blank after it.

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes I know. It was just a really fast answer and I didn't think it through.